# The best way to change array values at lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have a bi-dimensional array and I want to change the value at the *i*, *j* entry. Naturally, I would go with `(setf (aref foo i j) 3)`.

But my spider sense tells me that I use dozens of memory and processing, because if fell I am deleting and creating the array, in an interation, once, and once again.

How should I do?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Are you worried that `(setf (aref ...) ...)` is creating a copy of the array? If so, that is not the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@jkiiski is right in his comment. You are not creating copies of the array. You are modifying it in place.